# filtering a sublist of strings in C#

Tags: c#, list

I have an object which looks something like this

```
class MyObject
{
    string Name;
    string Description;
    List<string> Keywords;
}
```

And when I'm searching through these, I have a `List<MyObject> AllObjects`, which I want to filter based on the `Keywords`

```
var query = Request["q"];
//will only return exact matches
var exactHits = GetAll().Where(x => x.Keywords.Contains(query));
//I want something like this
var searchHits = GetAll().Where(x => x.Keywords.Contains(Regex.Match(query)));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Regex reg = new Regex(query);
var searchHits = GetAll().Where(x => x.Keywords.Any(k => reg.IsMatch(k)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure of the Regex.Match syntax, but it should be something like this:

```
var searchHits = GetAll().Where(x => x.Keywords.Any( k => Regex.Match(k, query).Success));
```

This will return all `MyObject`s where at least one of the keywords matches the query regex.

Comment: You were both right and answered at just about the same time, so I simply marked Petar's answer as correct based on StackOverflow-points.

Comment: No problem. Hope our answers helped you :)